# How can I pass "array" attribute (sent from springboot controller) from thymeleaf to Javascript and iterate?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My Springboot controller searches some park names and sends an array attribute to thymeleaf object. It displays as a list with other related things. Now I want to pass only names of the park to javascript function which is in separate file sothat I can display those parks on google maps. I am able to send single name (with document.getElementById()), need to know how to send entire array. Any pointers are helpful.

```
With hidden input type tag 
id="playgroundName" th:value="${park.name}" 
<input id="playgroundName" th:value="${park.name}"/> I can access single name with 
location = document.getElementById('playgroundName') 
But when I say hidden input tag with 
id="playgroundNames" th:value="${parkNames} 
<input id="playgroundNames" th:value="${parkNames}"/> 
console.log(location) shows entire <input> tag with following values
"[com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@718352, com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@16255f1, com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@13cb4d8, com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@14251f9, com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@1af2090, com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@3d2949, com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@b5d5e2, com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@12391d4, com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@13e81c0, com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@309a0f, com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@647ee, com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@16edc4b, com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@c572e7, com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@b77c92, com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@866c9d, com.aplaygroundreviewer.aplaygroundreviewer.models.Playground@1837b82]"
Need to know how to handle this data to exract names in javascript

    controller-

        @RequestMapping(value="results")
        public String search(Model model, @ModelAttribute SearchForm searchForm){
            model.addAttribute("parkNames", playgroundDao.findByNameContainingOrDescriptionContaining(searchForm.getName(), searchForm.getName()));
            return "search-results";
        }

thymeleaf file -
<table>
        <tr th:each="park: ${parkNames}">
                <input id="playgroundName" th:value="${park.name}" type="hidden"/>
                <td th:text="${park.name}"></td>
                <td th:text="${park.description}"></td>
                <td th:text="${park.address}"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
    ...

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&amp;libraries=places&amp;callback=initMap"
                async="async" defer="defer">
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did,

```
                    <tr th:each="park, itemStat: ${parkNames}">
                        <input id="playgroundName" th:name="|playgroundNames[${itemStat.index}]|"
                               th:value="${park.getName()}"
                               type="hidden"/>
                        <td><a th:href="@{/view/{id}(id=${park.id})}" th:text="${park.name}"></a></td>
                        <td th:text="${park.description}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${park.address}"></td>
                    </tr>
```

JavaSript

var locations = document.querySelectorAll("[id='playgroundName']");

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<th:block />` tag.

```
<table>
    <th:block th:each="park: ${parkNames}">
        <tr>
            <input id="playgroundName" th:value="${park.name}" type="hidden" />
            <td th:text="${park.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${park.description}"></td>
            <td th:text="${park.address}"></td>
        </tr>
    </th:block>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using html tags, you should be taking advantage of [JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining). You can do something like this to get access to the entire array of information:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var username = [[${parkNames}]];
</script>
```

Then you can act on the data however you want.